# How do I use Benjamini-Hochberg procedure for post-test segmentation in A/B-tests correctly?

Tags: statistical-significance, ab-test, false-discovery-rate

I am currently working on evaluating the results of an A/B-test. For this, I am also looking into some relevant post-test segments.

Overall, I have no statistically significant difference between control and test group. In my post-test segmentation, I have three types of segments:

- Segment type 1 is employment types which consist of 10 different values,
- segment type 2 is about search type which can have two different values and
- segment type 3 is new vs. existing users.

I know that for post-test segmentation you have to consider the multiple comparison problem and I tried to apply the Benjamini-Hochberg procedure on the segments.

However, I am not sure, if I only have to consider the variations inside each of the segment types or the total over all the segment types. E. g. if I want to know if search type 1 has a statistically significant better performance, do I only need to consider 2 variations as this segment type only consists of 2 variations, or do I need to take 14 variations into account (10 from segment type 1 + 2 from segment type 2 + 2 from segment type 3) as each look at the data increases my likelihood of finding false positives?

Currently, I am doing the first thing and have a statistically significant better performance for the test group on one of the search types.

Moreover, if I have statistically significant result according to this procedure, do I need to calculate the sample size again that I would need for this particular segment and make sure that the sample size is reached, so I can actually validly use the test results?

Thank you!